# Range not changing when using a QUERY inside an ARRAYFORMULA

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a large set of data stored in a spreadsheet and wish to extract some information from it.

Basically, I have 2 columns, `Email` and `Reference`. I used the following sample for my tests :

```
Email               Reference
-----------------------------
abc.xyz@corp.com    REF-0001
def.xyz@corp.com    REF-0002
def.xyz@corp.com    REF-0003
ghi.xyz@corp.com    REF-0004
jkl.xyz@corp.com    REF-0005
mno.uvw@corp.com    REF-0006
mno.uvw@corp.com    REF-0007
pqr.xyz@corp.com    REF-0008
pqr.xyz@corp.com    REF-0009
```

For each individual email, I want to list the references, as follow :

```
Email               References
-------------------------------------
abc.xyz@corp.com    REF-0001
def.xyz@corp.com    REF-0002,REF-0003
ghi.xyz@corp.com    REF-0004
jkl.xyz@corp.com    REF-0005
mno.uvw@corp.com    REF-0006,REF-0007
pqr.xyz@corp.com    REF-0008,REF-0009
```

I used the following formula to generate my `Reference` column in the results : `JOIN(","; UNIQUE(QUERY($A$3:$B; "select B where A='"&$D13&"'")))`, where `$D13` is the corresponding email address. This works perfectly fine when Drag&Dropping this formula into other cells.

However, when I try to use the following formula : `ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(D13:D);;JOIN(","; UNIQUE(QUERY($A$3:$B; "select B where A='"&D13:D&"'")))))`, only the value for D13 gets copied on all the cells of the range.

Why is taht ? Why is D13 considered a fixed value whereas the formula still expands ?

As I realize my question is a bit long, you can find the sample I used in the following link:

[LINK TO THE SPREADSHEET SAMPLE](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kWXpnLop96euum7_wUNpdz1WBTFGBWXzDwu6Qy_VQ6k)

Answer (score 0):

Not all Sheet functions can be used within an arrayformula, and my understanding is that neither QUERY nor UNIQUE will work in this way.